# Find nearest key in dictionary using decimal number keys

Tags: swift, dictionary, key, decimal, closest

I have some swift code where using a `datePicker`, once you click a button it tells you the difference in years and months between current date and chosen date using decimals.

So for example: today is march(0.3) 2015, and on the picker I chose december 2014. When I click the button it shows me correctly 0.4 or the difference between today and that date.

Now, I have some 400+ keys in my dictionary, all decimal numbers as:

```
var dict: [CGFloat: String] = [5.6: "blabla", 32.4: "bla", etc.]
```

How can I tell it to check if the number I get once I click the button, in my case `var completeNumber`, (let's say 6.7) is among the dictionary keys, and if it's not to go to the the next closest number/key?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary won’t do this out of the box, it will only give you exact key matches.

However, since it is a collection, you could write a function that searches for the closest match available, if given a distance function.  Here’s a generic function that will do that:

(note I have not spent much time debugging this, use with caution! :)

```
/// Search any collection for the index of the closest match, given a 
/// function to compute the distance between the elements and the target.
///
/// Returns nil in case of an empty collection.
func findClosestMatchTo<Col: CollectionType, Target, Distance: Comparable>
  (target: Target, within col: Col, #byDistance: (Target,Col.Generator.Element)->Distance) -> Col.Index? 
{
    var match: Col.Index? = nil
    var bestDistanceSoFar: Distance? = nil

    for (idx,elem) in zip(indices(col),col) {
        let thisDistance = byDistance(target, elem)
        if bestDistanceSoFar == nil || thisDistance < bestDistanceSoFar {
            match = idx
            bestDistanceSoFar = thisDistance
        }
    }

    return match
}

/// A convenience version for Strideable types, that can always have their distance computed
func findClosestMatchTo
  <Col: CollectionType where Col.Generator.Element: Strideable>
  (target: Col.Generator.Element, within col: Col) -> Col.Index? 
{
    return findClosestMatchTo(target, within: col) { abs($0 - $1) }
}

// prints 1 (index of 20)
println(findClosestMatchTo(100, within: [1,20,700,9]))
// prints 2 (index of 700)
println(findClosestMatchTo(1000, within: [1,20,700,9]))
```

Now, you just have to write the distance function such that it compares the key part of the key/value pair:

```
let dict: [CGFloat: String] = [1: "waffle", 5.6: "blabla", 32.4: "bla"]
let closest = findClosestMatchTo(5.5, within: dict) { abs($0 - $1.0) }
if let idx = closest {
    dict[idx]  // prints (5.6, “blabla”)
}
```

Of course, this algorithm is O(n) with respect to the size of the dictionary so if you find yourself constantly searching for matches but rarely inserting or looking up by key, you may want to look at a different data structure or algorithm (maybe a tree or a sorted array + binary search).

Answer (score 0):

Here is some horrible code that I wrote to get you started:

```
let items = [1.2: "Cheese", 4.3: "Bacon", 1.5: "Eggs", 8.5: "Toast"]

func findItemCloseTo(value: Double, inItems items: [Double: String]) -> (Double, String)? {
    if items.count == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    var foundNumber: Double?
    var foundString: String?

    var smallestDistance: Double = Double.infinity
    for (itemKey, itemValue) in items {
        let distance = fabs(itemKey - value)
        if distance < smallestDistance {
            smallestDistance = distance
            foundNumber = itemKey
            foundString = itemValue
        }
    }

    return (foundNumber!, foundString!)
}

findItemCloseTo(1.51, inItems: items) // Return(1.5, Eggs)
findItemCloseTo(3.0, inItems: items)  // Returns (4.3, Bacon)
findItemCloseTo(7.0, inItems: items)  // Returns (8.5, Toast)
```

I think the code would be simpler if you stored your data not in a dictionary but instead in an array of structs like:

```
struct Item {
    var decimalDate: Double
    var data: String
}
```

You could also optimize things then and sort the array to make the search quicker. With the dictionary you have to loop over all items since the keys are not stored in any sorted predictable way.